# Django redirect to Instagram

Tags: android, django, redirect, instagram

I'm creating a simple service in Django that redirects to Instagram social profiles.
I have some troubles with Android devices where, even if the Instagram appis installed, the link is opened in the browser.
I would like the link to be opened with the app, as already happens for iPhones.

Here is the code:

#### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('insta-bio/', views.redirect_to_url, name='redirect-to-url'),
]
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_to_url(request):
        my_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/thesimpsons/'
        return redirect(my_url)
```

I also tried with RedirectView type CBV, but nothing change...

Any advice???

Thank's!

Comment: If it works it works. Since it works on IOS, then you should look into what Android is not doing. Or maybe it is just on that particular device that the issue occurs on.